# Consuming from many queues

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a large number of state machines.  Occasionally, a state machine will need to be moved from one state to another, which may be cheap or expensive and may involve DB reads and writes and so on.

These state changes occur because of incoming commands from clients, and can occur at any time.

I want to parallelise the workload.  I want a queue saying 'move this machine from this state to this state'.  Obviously the commands for any one machine need to be performed in sequence, but I can be moving many machines forward in parallel if I have many threads.

I could have a thread per state machine, but the number of state machines is data-dependent and may be many hundreds or thousands; I don't want a dedicated thread per state machine, I want a pool of some sort.

How can I have a pool of workers but ensure that the commands for each state machine are processed strictly sequentially?

***UPDATE***: so imagine the `Machine` instance has a list of outstanding commands.  When an executor in the thread pool has finished consuming a command, it puts the `Machine` back into the thread-pool's task queue if it has more outstanding commands.  So the question is, how to atomically put the `Machine` into the thread pool when you append the first command?  And ensure this is all thread safe?

Comment: Check out [this article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/ensuring-order-execution-tasks). Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you this scenario:

1. Create thread pool, probably some of fix size with `Executors.newFixedThreadPool`
2. Create some structure (probably it would be a `HashMap`) which holds one `Semaphore` for each state machine. That semaphores will have a value of 1 and would be **fair** semaphores to keep sequence
3. In Runnable which will do the job on the begging just add `semaphore.aquire()` for semaphore of its state machine and `semaphore.release()` at the end of run method.

With size of thread pool you will control level of parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest another approach. Instead of using a threadpool to move states in a state machine, use a threadpool for everything, including *doing the work*. After doin some work resulting in a state-change the state-change event should be added to the queue. After the state-change is processed, another do-work event should be added to the queue.

Assuming that the state transition is work-driven, and vice-versa, asequential processing is not possible.

The idea with storing semaphores in a special map is very dangerous. The map will have to be synchronized (adding/removing objs is thread-unsafe) and there is relatively large overhead of doing the searches (possibly synchronizing on the map) and then using the semaphore.

Besides - if you want to use a multithreaded architecture in your application, I think that you should go all the way. Mixing different architectures may proove troublesome later on.

Comment: a very valid point; sorry I wasn't clear, these state changes are triggered externally and I want to queue them up internally.

Answer (score 1):

Have a thread ID per machine. Spawn the desired number of threads. Have all the threads greedily process messages from the global queue. Each thread locks the current message's server to be used exclusively by itself (until it's done processing the current message and all messages on its queue), and the other threads puts messages for that server on its internal queue.

**EDIT: Handling message pseudo-code:**

```
void handle(message)
  targetMachine = message.targetMachine
  if (targetMachine.thread != null)
    targetMachine.thread.addToQueue(message);
  else
    targetMachine.thread = this;
    process(message);
    processAllQueueMessages();
    targetMachine.thread = null;
```

**Handling message Java code:** (I may be overcomplicating things slightly, but this should be thread-safe)

```
/* class ThreadClass */
void handle(Message message)
{
  // get targetMachine from message
  targetMachine.mutexInc.aquire(); // blocking
  targetMachine.messages++;
  boolean acquired = targetMachine.mutex.aquire(); // non-blocking
  if (acquired)
    targetMachine.threadID = this.ID;
  targetMachine.mutexInc.release();
  if (!acquired)
    // can put this before release, it may speed things up
    threads[targetMachine.threadID].addToQueue(message);
  else
  {
    process(message);
    targetMachine.messages--;
    while (true)
    {
      while (!queue.empty())
      {
        process(queue.pop());
        targetMachine.messages--;
      }
      targetMachine.mutexInc.acquire(); // blocking
      if (targetMachine.messages > 0)
      {
        targetMachine.mutexInc.release();
        Thread.sleep(1);
      }
      else
        break;
    }
    targetMachine.mutex.release();
    targetMachine.mutexInc.release();
  }
}
```